# Omit -> Omission

Tags: suffixes

Why does *omit* turn to *omission* and not *omition*?

Examples of more words acting the same are welcome (I found *Submit*)

P.S. Is *Omission* the same as *Omitting*? (Trying to compare with *fit* -> *fitting*)

Comment: Also *intermit*

Comment: Also *admit* → *admission*; *commit* → *commission*. But these all seem to originate with the Latin verb *mittere* with various prefixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To omit and omission are words from Latin. Latin verbs developed a lot of irregularities, so the verb o-mitt-ere (infinitive) had the Perfect omisi and the third stem form omiss-us from which omission is derived.

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=omission&searchmode=none

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of Latin conjugation: the word "mitto" (I send) is the root of a number of such words and the perfect passive participle of mitto was "missum".

See also "remit" -> "remission".